# Xamarin Android List Sticky section headers with MvvmCross

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Trying to add iOS like sticky section headers to my Xamarin Android project. I have found this library https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/XamDroid.StickyListHeaders but we use MvvmCross so our list can't be both MvxList and StickyList. I don't want to lose the binding that the MvxList gives me.

Is there a way to do this without reimplementing the Sticky List Library?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a library for MvvmCross StickyHeadersList

https://github.com/Springham/MvvmCross.StickyHeadersList

It's copying functionality from https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/XamDroid.StickyListHeaders but allows binding.